# Can I upload image from mobile gallery to native app using appium

Tags: appium

I'm automating a native android app, where for profile image i need to upload image from mobile gallery or camera, is it possible using appium, if so explain me HOW?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible to upload image from gallery or via camera by APPIUM.**

If you are use `Android version 6.0` or above you should allow the permission, before entering the camera and gallery, you should use the full element for that like: `com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button`

For entering in gallery or capturing image you should also use the full element,
example for image capture button: `com.android.camera2:id/second_shutter_button`

Answer (score 0):

after clicking on application element which leads you to the options camera or gallery
for selecting photo options use this locator

`xpath` = "//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.widget.TextView[@text='Photos']"

for selecting gallery options use this locator

``xpath`= "//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.widget.TextView[@text='Gallery']"`

then after opening gallery or photo select a folder.
in this case I am selecting camera folder with `loactor`

`id = "`com.google.android.apps.photos:id`/image"`

then from the folder you have to choose a photo for this use this locator

``xpath`= "//android.view.ViewGroup[@index='1']"`

then control will goes to the native app which you are automating
but remember you need to have at least one photo in desired folder